# Are my Core Data relationships correct?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm working on something that displays a title of a list on a `UITableView`, and once the user selects a specific list it pushes to another `UITableView`, displaying all the items in that list including their properties, such as item name, price, ect. I will be using core data to save all of the data. I'm kinda new to Core Data; I have played around with it, but never used it in this way. So this is what I have so far, I'm not sure if it's right or if I'm going in the right direction. I have two entities one for the List and another for the name of the list.

[image]

Thats what I have so far, the relationships are what's confusing me. So if anyone could look over this and point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This tutorial will help you for working with core data relationships - http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you didn't well understand how to use Entities and Attributes:

> two entities one for the List and another for the name of the list

You should have one entity to hold the lists, and one entity to hold the items from the list. I don't understand your attributes either. Trying to keep what you've done as most as possible, I'd rename `WishList` to `Item` and `ListName` to `List`. The relationship inside `List` should then be named `items`. Now it makes sense, at least for me. You also don't need to write `itemName`, `itemPrice` and so on, they are already attributes inside an entity called `Item` - just name them: `name`, `price`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This relationship just means that there could be many WishList instances corresponded to ListName instance. Probably there couldn't appear any difficulty to change the relationship in future

Comment: @Jack Yes, If you're planning to have many WishList instances for one ListName than the diagram is OK.